# Is the source code to cordova plugins visible, just like that html and javascript code?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I understand that in a Cordova application, one can see the html, and javascript code easily. What about native (C++) plugins ? Is the source code to them visible as well ? I have just started learning about Cordova, so I don't fully understand how they are compiled as yet.

I am planning on using Cordova 5.x+

EDIT: This is not the same as the other question. This question is explicitly about whether one can see the source code of a native plugin. The other question is about whether someone else can reuse my native plugin without looking at the source code. For example, by looking at the js code, can one determine what api's to call on the native code and effectively reuse the native code as a library (without actually looking at the native source code)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can another developer extract and reuse my native plugin from a cordova app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32431172/can-another-developer-extract-and-reuse-my-native-plugin-from-a-cordova-app)

Comment: @jcesarmobile It is not the same question - one question is about whether we can see the source code, the other is about whether someone else can reuse the plugin without looking at the source code, but just knowing how to "call-in" to it.

Comment: yeah, but you can combine both, if the source code is visible, anyone can reuse it, if the source code ins't visible, it might still be used after decompiling