# Can another developer extract and reuse my native plugin from a cordova app?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I am creating a native plugin to use with my cordova app for some security specific functions (encryption / decryption etc). Can another developer extract the plugin from my app and use it ?

This is my first cordova app, so I don't fully understand how everything works yet.

EDIT:
In iOS - I will write the plugin in C++ & Objective-c
In Java, I will use JNI to access the C++.

Will the C++ source be viewable ?

Comment: And it has nothing to do with cordova, can native code be extracted? probably. You can make it harder creating a library/framework and ofuscating the code

Comment: @jcesarmobile I have not duplicated my own question. You have linked back to the same page. This question is not about extracting the native code. This is about just reusing the native plugin in another app without looking at how it works. Since the js can be seen, one can determine how to call the native code, even without looking at the native code itself. So my question is if the native plugin can be used in another app.

Comment: Sorry, this is the link I meant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32431129/is-the-source-code-to-cordova-plugins-visible-just-like-that-html-and-javascrip

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, i have not done it myself but im pretty sure you can extract any apk file

e.g. [how to extract code of apk file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888102/how-to-extract-code-of-apk-file)

e.g. http://www.decompileandroid.com/

I know that developers can create a "shell" of an app that once is downloaded will then dynamically download the rest of the app.

Hope it helps!